# Open my Mobile phone's message INBOX form midlet

Tags: java, java-me

I am making an J2ME application. I want open my mobile's Inbox from my  midlet(using a menu Button). i.e my application should be paused and my Inbox should be opened and when inbox is closed again my application should be loaded.

Purpose is that, If the user receives an sms while he is using my application he shud be directly able to open inbox from my application and once sms is read again resume my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve with j2me. You don't have the permission to access the Inbox, Outbox, and Sent items like that. For more info See this [Nokia forum discussion](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?160066-Can-we-access-sms-inbox-in-j2me).